# I abandoned or broke or aborted my thesis

Tags: word-usage

Which one can I say?

> I **abandoned or broke or aborted**   my thesis because I did not like the topic.

Comment: Which one strikes you as the best?

Answer (score 5):

As a native U.S English speaker, I would use "abandoned".

"Broke" is simply incorrect. "Aborted" is technically correct as well, but it sounds a little harsher, and can carry some negative emotional weight because it's a form of the word "abortion" (i.e., terminating a pregnancy). That said, there are some uses (like "abort the mission" mentioned in another answer) where "abort" is the normal and expected word.

Answer (score 3):

You would not use *broke*, but you could use either *abandoned* or *aborted*.

The word *abandoned* might suggest that it was a slower decision. If I woke up one morning and abruptly decided not to work on my thesis any longer, then I would have **aborted** the effort. On the other hand, if I gradually worked on it less and less over a period of several weeks, it might be more accurate to say that I had **abandoned** the effort. However, both verbs are a bit flexible, and I don't think that distinction always holds.

The verb *broke* is not a good fit, but the phrasal verb *break off* might work:

> I broke off my thesis work because I did not like the topic.

According to [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20off), to *break off* means "to discontinue".

Answer (score 2):

*Abandoned* is often used to describe properties or large objects that are no longer wanted by their owner, or that their owner has been forced to part with.  It can have the underlying meaning that the property/large object is unguarded and that a random person could trespass or take it, but not always.  This would be OK to use.

*Broke* is often used to describe physical things.  It's not used to talk about someone's work.

*Aborted* means an action was attempted and then halted when something bad happened.  The first thing that comes to mind with this word is *mission* in the sense of tactical or short-term goal, and it's a common term in computer-related nomenclature - e.g. aborted process, etc.  Things *aborted* cease to exist and have to be started over.  This would be appropriate if you just started your thesis and something caused you to have to start it all over, such as a fire or physically losing the papers.  If you were like 2 pages in to your thesis and decided to change topic, *aborted* would be appropriate to describe that as well.  If you are past the "halfway" point, *aborted* is probably not the word to use unless something really out of your control happened.